# How to send a Js-variable to the Server for php-array | Joomla

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, joomla, send

I just try to find the best way, 
to send a Js-variable to the Server for a further assessments,
but on one hand, I´m don't know Javascript on the other, I've
no overview of the scope of technics beeing in run. 
May be somebody can help me?

In a Joomla 3.1.x environment with jQuery I have this function 
(here in php $js-string):

```
$js    .= "
function cont_printSelection() {
    var sel = cal5.selection.print('%Y%m%d', ' -> ');
    if (sel.length == 0) sel = 'No date selected';
        else
    sel = sel.join(\n);
    alert(sel);        };
    ";
```

'sel' gives something simply like "20130904 -> 20130906, 20130908"
therefrom I need an php-array.

How you would send it to the server?
I heard somsthing about `XMLHttpRequest`

or JSON

or send it as hidden field?

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" value="sel">
</form>
```

Whats moste secure and perform?
I think, without Js/Ajax its not possible because of required reloadings?

And: all in the Joomla 3.1.x-environment.
May be, J! has something well prepared for this occasion?

Rob

Comment: Don't know joomla, but you can set the hidden field in the form with the data.  if you want it in JSON, it needs to look like `{"20130904":"20130906"}`  Where the left side is the key and the right is the value.  You can then use php `json_decode($json, true)` on the php side to use the data like a regular php array.  Anything you produce in javascript is fully visible to everyone.  If security is an issue here you may want to go another route.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is called `Ajax` these days. Process that you want to do is called "serialization" - on JS side and "unserialization" - at PHP side

Comment: Ultra, @Jacob,
Thanks! Until now, I can't see, why/how I *just* can send this plain string "20130904 -> 20130906, 20130908", I see in the alert-Notice?

Answer (score 0):

use cookie. 
javascript http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
php http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php
can not be removed javascript_cookie c using php and vice versa.